# Do I need separate subnets when deploying multiple API Management stages / lifecycles in internal mode?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-api-management, azure-application-gateway

According to the article [Integrate API Management in an internal VNET with Application Gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-integrate-internal-vnet-appgateway) I need separate subnets in a VNET for APIM and AppGW instances. I want to deploy 3 lifecycles / stages (DEV,QA,PROD) in that model. Does that mean I need 3 times 2 subnets or can I put all 3 APIM staged in one subnet and all 3 AppGW instances in the other subnet?

Comment: I was just thinking. Somewhere the docs where stating that you should not have other Azure resources in the same subnets as APIM. I thought that may be this restriction applies also to APIM itsself - only one instance in a subnet.

Comment: I don't follow, what do you mean exactly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can deploy multiple APIM into a single subnet. That is you can host all your Dev, QA, Prod instances inside a single subnet, having the same networking constraints.

The only restriction is that you cannot share that subnet with another resource like App Gateway.

Comment: thanks @Samir - we will give that a shot and when working I'll flag the answer

Comment: Hey @KaiWalter, did you try us out?

Comment: deployment of 2 AppGw in 1 subnet and 2 APIM in 1 subnet worked, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, technically nothing prevents you from using 2 subnets total, 1 for APIM, 1 for APPGA.

And why would you need more than 1 API management?

Comment: Why more than 1 APIM: do you know another way to have 3 stages of APIs exposed?

Comment: inside apim you can have as many apis separated from each other @KaiWalter